# A PHP Error was encountered:Message: Undefined variable: number

Tags: php

PLEASE HELP OUT, AM NEW AT THIS... GETTING THIS LOGIN ERROR WHEN EVER A CLIENT LOGIN...A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: number

Filename: controllers/Site.php

Line Number: 42

Backtrace:

> File: /home/rocketmoney/public_html/application/controllers/Site.php
>   Line: 42 Function: _error_handler
>
> File: /home/rocketmoney/public_html/index.php Line: 315 Function:
>   require_once

HERE IS MY CONTROLLER CODES

```
<?php
if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
    if ($this->core_model->login()) {
        $query = $this->db->get_where('users', array('number' => $number));
        $result = $query->row_array();
        $name = $result['name'];
        $bank_details = $result['bank_details'];
        $session_data = array('number' => $_POST['number'], 'loggedin' => TRUE, 'name' => $name);
        $this->session->set_userdata($session_data);
        redirect(site_url('dash'));
    }
}?>
```

Comment: where is the $number variable ?? where you have defined that??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Comment: You do know that all caps is considering screaming? Not nice to scream at people, specially when you're asking them for help.

Comment: That error message is very clear and self explanatory.

Comment: Sorry about the screaming stuff...

Comment: $query = $this->db->get_where('users', array('number' => $number));

Comment: i dont know what is wrong with that line... i need help please

Comment: The error message is: "Undefined variable: $number". You haven't defined the variable `$number` before trying to use it. It's actually hard to explain it any more clear than that.

Comment: Thank you... have been able to resolve it

Comment: $query = $this->db->get_where('users', array('number' => $number = 'dash'));

Comment: @itoroihkpessii - The above solution is the exact same thing as writing: `array('number' => 'dash')`. No need to use the variable `$number` at all, in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly this is a risky code because what if `$result` array is `null`? what if `$result` array doesn't have `name` and `bank_details` index?

By the way, if you are just concern only about the error you are getting, then: Before your `if` condition just add the following line:

`$number = isset($number) ? $number : '';`

This line will set the number variable with the previous number variable is it exist otherwise it will put empty string on that number variable. Your provided code doesn't give any hint whether the number variable is being set above this code. So if it isn't set then what are you checking in the `where` condition? You are getting the error. So, this line should solve this compilation error but you may still have any logical error.